# Expressão Regular - Apenas números, sem espaço

Tags: regex

Eu tenho a seguente expressão regular '`((?:[\d][\s]?){5}[\d])`' e estou testando ela no https://regex101.com/.

O meu problema é o seguinte: Se eu tiver esse trecho '`teste 123456 teste`' ela vai me retorna apenas '`123456`' o que está correto. Mas se for '`teste 12 345 6 teste`' ela me retorna '`12 345 6`'.

Gostaria de saber um jeito para ela retorna apenas os números sem os espaços, se acaso tiver espaços.

Comment: Há alguma restrição na quantidade de dígitos que você quer? Aquele `{5}` sugere que sim. Caso haja, qual seria exatamente essa restrição?

Comment: Não sei qual linguagem está usando, mas se é JavaScript você pode fazer o processo inverso. Exemplo: 'teste 12 345 6 teste'.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, o que é pra retornar se o valor de entrada for `teste 1.324,33 manamana 52` ?

Comment: Ou se o valor for `teste 12 345 xxx 6 teste`? Ele deveria retornar `123456` ou deveria rejeitar por causa do `xxx`?

Answer (score 3):

#### Remover tudo exceto números

```
"teste 123456 teste".replace(/\D/g, '');   // 123456
"teste 12 345 6 teste".replace(/\D/g, ''); // 123456
```

#### Capturar tudo que é numero e espaço, mas considerar os números

```
var input = "teste 12 345 6 teste"; // string teste
var regex = /(\d+)| /g;             // regex

var matches, output = [];           // vars para processo
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {  // captura do contudo, o exec vai capturar 
                                       // o primeiro resultado que encontrar seja 
                                       // `\d` ou ` `, quando capturar ` ` não 
                                       // haverá grupo 1, assim ao fazer o `matches[1]` 
                                       // este estará `undefined` que no filter é 
                                       // false, assim o eliminando do array.

    output.push(matches[1]);        // adiciona o grupo 1 a out
}
output.filter(function(value){
  return value;                     // limpeza do array
}).join('')                         // concatena tudo por join
```

Resultado : `123456`

Comment: Oops: "`teste 12 345 xxx 6 teste`"

Comment: @VictorStafusa o resultado foi o mesmo, o que desejas sabe?

Comment: É porque nesse caso, ele NÃO deveria aceitar isso, uma vez que os seis números não estão apenas separados por espaços.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci algo aqui :S

Comment: No meu teste eu coloquei o `g`, ao reescrever aqui eu esqueci.

Comment: O problema não é só o `g`. O problema é achar seis números seguidos separados por espaços e não seis números seguidos separados por qualquer coisa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ai teria que perguntar pro autor como ele quer, pq pelo que eu vi na pergunta, não dá pra ter certeza do que é melhor pra ele se for `teste 1.234.45 manamana 4`, por exemplo. Deixei um comment na pergunta pra ver se a gente consegue mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Se for exatamente para essa expressão que diz no comentário, faz assim que dá. Se naum bota as possíveis variáveis, que agente acerta...

```
"(\b[0-9]\b)/g"
```

Se for suficiente da ok na resposta, se naum comenta que agente acerta...

Comment: Então MagicHat... assim não dá... se minha string estiver nesse formato 'teste 1 2 3 4 5 6 test2 edf 4452 rdf' essa expressão não vai me trazer a sequencia se 6 quem podem ou não esta com espaço (ela irá trazer todos os números). Eu quero que ela me traga apenas os 6 números dessa sequencia, mas me traga sem os espaços...

Comment: Luis, se vc estiver utilizando o regex101.com, lembre-se que o `/g` vai no outro campo da expressão ... recomendo que utilize o regexpal.com

Answer (score 2):

Expressões regulares servem para reconhecer caracteres dentro de uma string. Com elas você também pode obter qual foi a substring reconhecida.

Ocorre que `123456` não é substring de `teste 12 345 6 teste`. E portanto, você não vai conseguir obter `123456` como resposta usando apenas regex em um único passo porque `123456` não está exatamente desse jeito na string de entrada.

Então você faz o seguinte:

1. Usa o `((?:[\d][\s]?){5}[\d])` para localizar o número com os espaços.
2. Tira os espaços posteriormente usando um `replace`.

Answer (score -3):

REGEX para telefone para quem estiver precisando em C#:

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex tel = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[^0-9, \s, (, ), -]");

Aceita apenas os formatos (XX) XXXXX-XXXX

qualquer coisa fora disso ele rejeita!

Comment: Antes de sair escrevendo qualquer coisa num site de conteúdo técnico procure o [manual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para não trazer desconforto para os outros usuários. O Stack Overflow [não é um fórum, não é rede social, site de ajuda, blog ou grupo de discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) e o espaço que usou é destinado exclusivamente para publicação de soluções ao problema enunciado na página. Não use esse espaço para publicar recados e dicas aleatórias.

Comment: Para conhecer mais do funcionamento e filosofia do site leia [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/137387), siga os links da [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387), veja [answer], [META] e principalmente faça o nosso [tour].