# String contendo apenas números

Tags: json, regex

Estou precisando de uma expressão regular para uma string receber apenas números, por exemplo:

```
"12454853", "12", "9012"
```

Esses são válidos, mas preciso que quando aparecer uma string como:

```
"123g123", "123er*"
```

Ele dê como inválido.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Expressão Regular - Apenas números, sem espaço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136774/express%c3%a3o-regular-apenas-n%c3%bameros-sem-espa%c3%a7o)

Comment: Essa expressão, está dando match de um por vez, preciso que seja dentro de toda a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar esta regex:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Os marcadores `^` e `$` indicam, respectivamente, o [início e final](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) da string. Isso garante que a string só terá, do início ao fim, o que estiver especificado entre o `^` e `$`.

Os colchetes (`[]`) indicam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): eles servem para indicar que você quer qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles. No caso eu usei `0-9`, que significa "os dígitos de 0 a 9". Portanto, `[0-9]` aceita qualquer dígito de 0 a 9.

O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" do que está imediatamente antes dele. No caso, `[0-9]+` significa "um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9".

Ou seja, esta regex verifica se há um ou mais dígitos, do início ao fim da string. Se tiver qualquer outro caractere, ela falha.

Veja a regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/6OHaQc/1).

---

Para os dígitos você também pode usar o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`, que é equivalente a `[0-9]`, então a regex ficaria:

```
^\d+$
```

O único detalhe é que dependendo da linguagem/engine/configuração, o `\d` também pode corresponder a [outros caracteres que representam dígitos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), como por exemplo os caracteres `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩` (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes).

Como não está claro qual a linguagem/engine/configuração você está usando, eu diria para usar `[0-9]`, assim você garante que somente os dígitos de 0 a 9 serão aceitos.

Comment: Tem ainda outra alternativa que é usar as funções nativas da linguagem que vc está usando para verificar se a string só tem números (toda linguagem tem algo do tipo, e dependendo do caso pode até ser mais simples que regex). Mas enfim, a solução com regex é essa... :)

Answer (score 1):

Veja o regex no código abaixo:

```js
var regex = /[0-9]/g;

var valor1 = "12312312";
var valor2 = "asdfad";


if(regex.test(valor1)){
  console.log("valor válido");
}else {
  console.log("valor inválido");
}


if(regex.test(valor2)){
  console.log("valor válido");
}else {
  console.log("valor inválido");
}
```